# How do I show or hide specific content in JavaScript/jQuery with linked elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, toggle

I have a pretty specific need in JavaScript/jQuery and I can’t find the perfect solution, there is always a criterion that I can’t fulfill.

Here is a summary of the situation:
I have 3 titles each with their own id and a common class.
I also have 3 contents each with their own id and a common class.

At the code level, it looks like this:

```
<h3 id="title1" class"triggers">Title 1</h3> 
<h3 id="title2" class"triggers">Title 2</h3> 
<h3 id="title3" class"triggers">Title 3</h3>

<p id="content1" class="myContents">Content 1</p> 
<p id="content2" class="myContents">Content 2</p> 
<p id="content3" class="myContents">Content 3</p>
```

My constraints are as follows:

- all content is hidden by default
- when I click on a title, the related content is displayed (Ex: I click on the title1 the content1 is displayed) and the selected title changes color
- When I click on another title, the one that was previously selected returns to its original color and its content disappears. On the other hand, the title I just clicked on changes its color and its specific content appears (Ex: I click on the title2, the title1 returns to its original color and the content1 disappears while the title2 changes color and the content2 appears). Only one content can appear at a time.
- When I click a second time on the currently selected title, it returns to its original color and its content disappears (but if I click a third time, it reappears again, basically one shot it appears and one shot it disappears, so a click on two).
- That the title id is automatically attached to the content id (since in my example, there are only 3 titles and 3 contents but there could very well be 20, 30, etc.).

A situation in appearance "basic" for the common developers, except that I can not meet all these conditions at the same time, there is always a time when it sticks... Be lenient, I’m still a beginner in the trade

So if you are able to help me solve this block, I would be enormously grateful! Thanking you already for the time you will take to read me :)

So far, I have managed to meet some of my requirements on the display of content, but I have not managed to fulfill all these requirements at the same time.

Comment: You forgot to paste the JS you're having issues with. Read: [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve].

Comment: Also, where's the `=` in the attribute `class"triggers"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple requirements I would just toggle some data attribute values and match up the CSS; you can put any selector in that matches the target, then toggle that.  You can even have "special" css as I show for the Five element - or even have a stoplight effect with Green/Yellow/Red etc. this way.

I added a couple more targets with differing selectors just so you could see it is flexible.

Note that you could even have TWO and wrap them in a div so the siblings matches.  Triggers and Content can be in any order as long as the selectors match.

```js
function handleTriggerClick(event) {
  const trig = this;
  const tval = trig.dataset.clicker;
  //reset all triggers
  this.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".triggers").forEach(sib => sib.dataset.clicker = "base");
  // set this trigger
  trig.dataset.clicker = tval !== "red" ? "red" : "base";
  const targS = trig.dataset.related;
  // get the target from the selector in the attribute
  const tC = document.querySelector(targS);
  //reset the targets siblings (and it) 
  tC.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".myContents").forEach(sib => sib.dataset.trigger = "hide");
  // set to show
  tC.dataset.trigger = "first";
}

document.querySelectorAll(".triggers[data-related]").forEach(trig => {
  trig.addEventListener("click", handleTriggerClick, false);
  trig.dataset.clicker = "base"
});
```

```css
.triggers[data-clicker="base"] {
  color: blue;
}

.triggers[data-clicker="red"] {
  color: red;
}

.myContents[data-related] {
  display: none;
}

.myContents[data-trigger="first"] {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

.myContents[data-trigger="first"][data-related="five"] {
  display: block;
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 15em;
  text-align:center;
  border: solid 1px #00ff0080;
}

.myContents[data-trigger="hide"] {
  display: hide;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="title1" class="triggers" data-related="#content1">Title 1</h3>
<h3 id="title2" class="triggers" data-related="#content2">Title 2</h3>
<h3 id="title3" class="triggers" data-related="#content3">Title 3</h3>
<h3 class="triggers four" data-related=".myContents.four">Title 4</h3>
<h3 class="triggers" data-related=".myContents[data-related='five']">I am number 5</h3>

<p id="content1" class="myContents" data-related="#title1">Content 1</p>
<p id="content2" class="myContents" data-related="#title2">Content 2</p>
<p id="content3" class="myContents" data-related="#title3">Content 3</p>
<p class="myContents four" data-related=".triggers.four">Content 4</p>
<p class="myContents" data-related="five">Five is alive!</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer too, but as with the previous answer, not all the conditions are met.

When you click on the selected title again, it changes back to blue (its original colour) but the content attached to it is still displayed. The title would have to revert to blue AND its content would have to disappear when it was clicked again.

Comment: What's more, as I said in my problem, ideally I'd like to be able to use only the "id" and "class" attributes (I'm using a plugin to solve my problem and I can't add any attributes other than these two). 

I'm continuing to look for ways of doing this myself, thank you for your ideas.

So thank you for your suggestion and for the time you've taken to answer me in any case :)

Comment: The "not show" can be solved by just checking the current value of the target on the click; I can update later but no time at the moment.  This CAN be done with classes but the code is going to be a bit more, and you CAN add data attributes just from code also instead of a "starting html" as I have here.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
       
        <title>Java Script Function and Event Example</title>
        <style>
            
            #content1,#content2,#content3
            {
                visibility: hidden;
            }
           
            .highlight
            {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
            $(document).ready(function() {

                
                $("#title1").click(function(e) {
                    $('*').removeClass('highlight');
                    $(this).addClass('highlight');

                    $("#demo").text($("#content1").text());
                });

                $("#title2").click(function() {
                    $('*').removeClass('highlight');
                    $(this).addClass('highlight');
                   
                    $("#demo").text($("#content2").text());
                });

                $("#title3").click(function() {
                    $('*').removeClass('highlight');
                    $(this).addClass('highlight');
                   
                    $("#demo").text($("#content3").text());
                });
    
            });  
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
<h3 id="title1" class"triggers">Title 1</h3> 
<h3 id="title2" class"triggers">Title 2</h3> 
<h3 id="title3" class"triggers">Title 3</h3>

<p id="content1" class="myContents">Content 1</p>
<p id="content2" class="myContents">Content 2</p> 
<p id="content3" class="myContents">Content 3</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but as with my personal tests, not all the conditions have been met.

In fact, when you click again on the selected title, the content attached to it is still displayed and the title remains in red. The title would have to change back to black and its content would have to disappear when you clicked on it again.

What's more, as I said in my problem, I'd like to have a function with factorised blocks of code that give the desired behaviour to the different elements without duplicating code.

Comment: In your solution, it's fine if you only have 3 or 4 clickable titles. If we have 30 or 40, the function will be very/too large and will be difficult to maintain.

But thank you for your proposal and for the time you've taken to reply :)